# Can't seem to add values to the database using while loop

Tags: php, mysql, session

This is a page for adding beneficiaries of a specific user in a health aid program. First page just asks for the number of beneficiaries and prints the x number of form rows depending on the input. 1 row has 4 fields: lastname, firstname, age, and relationship. But I can't add them to the database using addBeneficiary.php. Here's my codes:

HealthAidBeneficiary.php

```
<div>
     <?php
         $_SESSION["BeneficiaryNo"] = $_POST["beneficiary"];
         $i = 1;
         while ($i <= $_SESSION["BeneficiaryNo"]){
          echo "
          <div class=\"row\">
            <div>
              <label>Last Name</label>
              <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Last Name\" name=\"lastname".$i."\">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>First Name</label>
              <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"First Name\"name=\"firstname".$i."\">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Age</label>
              <input type=\"number\" placeholder=\"Age\" name=\"age".$i."\">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Relationship</label>
              <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Relationship\" name=\"relationship".$i."\">
            </div>
          </div>";
          $i++;
         }
      ?>
 </div>
```

addBeneficiary.php

```
$BeneficiaryNo = $_SESSION["BeneficiaryNo"];
$healthaid_id = $_SESSION["healthaid_id"]; //never mind this

$i = 1;
while ($i <= $BeneficiaryNo){
              $lastname = $_POST["lastname"."$i"];
              $firstname = $_POST["firstname"."$i"];
              $age = $_POST["age"."$i"];
              $relationship = $_POST["relationship"."$i"];
              $query1 = "INSERT healthaid_beneficiary (healthaid_id, lastname, firstname, age, relationship) VALUES ('$healthaid_id', '$lastname' , '$firstname', '$age' , '$relationship')";
              $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
              if (!$result1) {echo mysql_error($connectDB);}
              $i++;
            }
header("Location: ../FacultyHome.php");
```

I know it's either the way I called the values and/or typed the query in the addBeneficiary.php. Can somebody help? Thanks!

Comment: try to echo your query and run in mySQL..you will get your error

Comment: Have you tried echoing or var_dumping() the $_POST to see that you're accessing the right keys? Also try echoing $_POST["lastname"."$i"] to see if that key exists.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use PDO. And the query should be: INSERT INTO not INSERT only

```
 $BeneficiaryNo = $_SESSION["BeneficiaryNo"];
    $healthaid_id = $_SESSION["healthaid_id"]; //never mind this

    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= $BeneficiaryNo){
                  $lastname = $_POST["lastname"."$i"];
                  $firstname = $_POST["firstname"."$i"];
                  $age = $_POST["age"."$i"];
                  $relationship = $_POST["relationship"."$i"];
                  $query1 = "INSERT INTO healthaid_beneficiary (healthaid_id, lastname, firstname, age, relationship) VALUES ('$healthaid_id', '$lastname' , '$firstname', '$age' , '$relationship')";
                  $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
                  if (!$result1) {echo mysql_error($connectDB);}
                  $i++;
                }
    header("Location: ../FacultyHome.php");
```

In PDO would be like this:

```
$hostdb="";
$namedb="";
$userdb="";
$passdb="";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO healthhaid_beneficiary (healthaid_id, lastname, firstname, age, relationship) VALUES(:uid, :lname, :fname, :age, :relation) ;
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindValue(":uid", $healthaid_id);
            $statement->bindValue(":lname", $lastname);
            $statement->bindValue(":fname", $firstname);
            $statement->bindValue(":age", $age);
            $statement->bindValue(":relation", $relationship);
$count = $statement->execute();

        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

tweaked around a little bit and seemed to fix it: removed the quotes of the $i inside the $_POST and others. here's the complete code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "") or die (mysql_error($conn));
    mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn);

    $UserID = $_SESSION["UserID"];
    $PayrollGroup = $_SESSION["Status"];
    $BeneficiaryNo = $_SESSION["BeneficiaryNo"];
    $healthaid_id = $_SESSION["healthaid_id"];

    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= $BeneficiaryNo){
              $lastname = $_POST['lastname'.$i];
              $firstname = $_POST['firstname'.$i];
              $age = $_POST['age'.$i];
              $relationship = $_POST['relationship'.$i];

              $query = "INSERT healthaid_beneficiary (healthaid_id, lastname, firstname, age, relationship) VALUES ('$healthaid_id', '$lastname' , '$firstname', '$age' , '$relationship')";
              $result = mysql_query($query);
              $i++;
            }

if (!$result) {
  echo mysql_error($conn);
} else {
  header("Location: ../FacultyHome.php");
}

?>
```